# Physics.OverlapSphere not detecting colliders correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing an AI "minigame" in Unity for a College Assigment. I'm trying to make simple agents moving inside a walkable mesh using steerings. Right now I'm with the Flocking steering and I'm using the method showed in [this article](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-simple-rules-of-flocking-behaviors-alignment-cohesion-and-separation--gamedev-3444).

The problem I'm having is that the OverlapSphere function doesn't return the colliders correctly as you can see in the image:

[image: Scene]

Here's the code I'm using for the steering. The 8 in the Overlap Sphere call is the layer where the colliders used for this steering are located.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SteeringFlocking : SteeringAbstract
{
    Move move;
    public uint detection_radius = 5;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        move = GetComponent<Move>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Collider[] agents_near = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, detection_radius, 8);

        if (agents_near.Length > 0)
        {
            Vector3 final = Alignment(agents_near) + Cohesion(agents_near) + Separation(agents_near);
            move.AccelerateMovement(final.normalized * move.max_mov_acceleration, priority);
        }

    }

    private Vector3 Alignment(Collider[] agents_near)
    {
        Vector3 result = Vector3.zero;

        for (uint i = 0; i < agents_near.Length; ++i)
        {
            result += agents_near[i].gameObject.GetComponent<Move>().movement;
        }

        result.x /= agents_near.Length;
        result.y /= agents_near.Length;
        result.z /= agents_near.Length;
        result.Normalize();

        return result;
    }

    private Vector3 Cohesion(Collider[] agents_near)
    {
        Vector3 result = Vector3.zero;

        for (uint i = 0; i < agents_near.Length; ++i)
        {
            result += agents_near[i].gameObject.transform.position;
        }

        result.x /= agents_near.Length;
        result.y /= agents_near.Length;
        result.z /= agents_near.Length;
        result = new Vector3(result.x - move.transform.position.x, result.y - move.transform.position.y, result.z - move.transform.position.z);
        result.Normalize();

        return result;
    }

    private Vector3 Separation(Collider[] agents_near)
    {
        Vector3 result = Vector3.zero;

        for (uint i = 0; i < agents_near.Length; ++i)
        {
            result += agents_near[i].gameObject.transform.position - move.transform.position;
        }

        result.x /= agents_near.Length;
        result.y /= agents_near.Length;
        result.z /= agents_near.Length;
        result *= -1;
        result.Normalize();

        return result;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, detection_radius);
    }
}
```

The expected result is the OverlapSphere returning correctly the number of colliders inside it.

Comment: Sorry, thought Gyazo picked that info and I didn't stopped to revise it, it returns always a 0 as if there was any collider overlapping the sphere.

Comment: Hi Victor, if you found a solution to this issue, please share it with us. Thank you.

Comment: Not answering the question, but in my case, OverlapSphere couldn't be used with 2D colliders.

Answer (score 2):

> The 8 in the Overlap Sphere call is the layer where the colliders used for this steering are located.

`8` and a bitmask of Layer #8 are not the same thing.

`8` is just `8`. A bitmask of layer #8 is equal to `1<<8` or 256.

Additionally, it does not appear that your characters are not on layer 8, but on layer 0, so of course your OverlapSphere is going to return zero colliders (unless the children are on a different layer, the screenshot did not make that clear).

You'll want this instead:

```
Collider[] agents_near = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, detection_radius, 1<<8);
```

As well as changing your object to actually *be* on Layer 8 (though I would pick a different one, as Unity has hard-coded layer 8's name as `Post Processing` which does not have the contextual value you want for your purposes).

*OR*

```
Collider[] agents_near = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, detection_radius, 1<<0); //cast against layer 0.
```

See: [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html).

Comment: Yes, they have a children with the collider in mask 8 as you can se [here](https://i.gyazo.com/d5d5486c89c259013d90001b56089c88.png).
I tried what you said to me but it doesn't seem to fix the problem, even though I changed all the mask to ```9``` also (not in the screenshot)

Comment: I can't actually tell what layer number your collider is assigned to, I can [only see its *name*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiSmn.png). If you changed it to 9, you need to also change your code (to `1<<9`). You may also be interested in [`LayerMask.NameToLayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.NameToLayer.html)

Comment: Yes, I already changed after doing the screenshot, although I'm gonna use ```LayerMask.NameToLayer``` better. The code reads correctly the layer because it logs ```9``` in the console using ```Debug.Log``` of the ```LayerMask.NameToLayer``` but it doesn't detect the colliders yet sadly.

Comment: The error I'm getting is ```NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object SteeringFlocking.Alignment (UnityCollider[] agents_near```.

Comment: I didn't think OverlapSphere returned null in the event of no touches, but its been a while since I've messed with it. I'm honestly baffled here. :\